# validating dynamically generated textbox using regularexpressionvalidator

Tags: asp.net, validation

iam dynamically generating two `textboxes` on add `textbox` `button` which is working fine but i want to validate the value of that `textboxes` as well but when i apply validation and run the page and click add button nothing happens when i debug the code there is no error and the control executes all the lines but if i comment the validation code then add button works fine
see here

```
        TextBox addtimeout = new TextBox();
        addtimeout.ID = "addtimeout" + j;
        addtimeout.EnableViewState = true;
        PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(addtimeout);

        RegularExpressionValidator rev = new RegularExpressionValidator();
        rev.ValidationExpression = "^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$";
        rev.ControlToValidate = addtimeout.Text;
        rev.ErrorMessage = "Invalid time format. Time format HH:MM AM/PM";
        rev.Enabled = true;
        PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(rev);

        PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

tell me what i am doing wrong??

**UPDATE**

```
rev.ControlToValidate = addtimeout.ID;
```

still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Control to Validate Requires the Id of your control i.e. but you are passing the text of your text box so to make it work.

Change

```
rev.ControlToValidate = addtimeout.Text;
```

to

```
rev.ControlToValidate =addtimeout.ID;
```

Control to Validate Requires the Id of your control i.e. but you are passing the text of your text box

Comment: @MohsinMustufa it still not validating i mean it show error message or not

Comment: @MohsinMustufa do u have any validation group in button or on page

Answer (score 0):

Generally...IF you make dynamic code for validation than try to add validationGroup property...to make consistant validation...